# Django - Model Meta options app_label not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following Django app structure

```
apps
    ├── apartment
    │   ├── migrations
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── models
    │   │   ├── apartment.py
    │   │   ├── core.py
```

I added `apps.apartment.apps.ApartmentConfig` to `INSTALLED APPS`. And `apartment.py` look like:

```
class Apartment(Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'apartment'
```

When I run makemigrations, it says **no changes detected**. And I wrote following code in my `apps.py`.

```
class ApartmentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.apartment'
    def ready(self):
        print(self.label)  # returns 'apartment'
        from .models.apartment import Apartment
```

Now it is working fine. Should I always do this when writing a new model?. As a [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#app-label) says:

> If a model is defined outside of an application in INSTALLED_APPS, it must declare which app it belongs to:
>   `app_label = 'myapp'`

Can anyone explain me why it's not working? Are there better ways to solved this without importing all the models?

Comment: Explain your problem in detail scenario, also add some link possibly.

Comment: What do you mean add some link?